# My iPhone could not be restored. An unknown error occurred (4014)

Tags: iphone, ios, restore

Error 4014 occurred when restoring my iPhone 6s I have restarted my iPhone, but it didn't help. I don't know what to do next.

Why did it happen?

Answer (score 1):

The why is a quality check where the Apple software tests for a response from your phone and that response wasn’t measured.

If I can assume you want a process to narrow this down, here is a guide.

- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201252

At the end, errors have some general fixes like restart and update. I would do all of them, they really fix many errors.

- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201210

At the end of all updates is a list of more errors, but I would do all the easy items first before getting to the page that lists specific error codes. Yours is quite involved and wants you to choose update or restore based on previous steps and really wants updates and restarts of the device before contacting Apple if you can’t get past the check.

- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201444

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. I have used all the solutions from the Apple website you recommended me, but this error still appears. I don't know what should I do next.

Comment: @SylviaWatson I’ve not had issues with the procedures above. Did you complete them?  What happened when you followed this link in the KB above? http://www.apple.com/support/contact/

Comment: These days, I try those ways above again. Luckily, my iPhone didn't appear error 4014 again. Appreciate your help again!

Comment: Wonderful! Glad to hear it sorted over time